# Controlling LEDs with multiple controllers

Tags: led, diodes, control-system

I have three black boxes each controlling an LED output. Each black box takes an input voltage and provides an output voltage (ranging from 0-12V) to illuminate the LED.

Is it possible to alternate between a selected black box and have a common LED? Would I need a component such as a diode where there is the dotted line to prevent current entering the other two controllers?

I would appreciate some help with this. Many thanks.

[image: Block Diagram of intended circuit]

Comment: Open collector / open drain an option? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_collector

Answer (score 2):

Assuming each already has a resistor at the output that limits the current through the led to 5~20mA, a transistor at each output will work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8cBQt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If any of the outputs is high, the led will be on.

Comment: What about if the signal is analogue (varying between 0V and 12V)?

Comment: @Michael is it?

Comment: Yes, the controllers fade the LEDs, so I would imagine so.

Comment: @Michael so its PWM? That's important to note in the question. That said, a transistor will work with PWM, but the amount of current through the output is important.

Comment: I don't really know exactly what it is or how they work.

Comment: It is similar to this I have found on the internet, only it is for one colour of LED. http://www.nationallighting.co.uk/LED_Lighting/LED_Fittings/LED_Strip_Lighting/microflex_accessories/pid/551

Comment: @Michael that goes to common anode rgb strips. They are controlled by PWM, where the output is 0V or 12V, rapidly switching between the two, instead of ranging from 0 to 12V.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the information. In this case then, can I use the circuit you have provided to allow the LED to be to be shared between similar devices? Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

A simple diode from each box to the LED will work, if by "work" you mean "protect the controllers from each other." If you want some way to let each controller take control of the LED, that's a different story.

If each box puts out a DC voltage, using diodes will cause the LED to light to the greatest brightness commanded by any of the 3 controllers. If the output is a PWM waveform, the output will vary wildly with time, from the greatest commanded brightness to as much as full on.

If you insist on connecting all three controllers to the same LED, you'll have to make sure that the "unused" controllers are set to zero brightness. If you do that, a simple set of diodes will work fine, regardless of how the controllers work.